# Python class method: Extracting two of eight attributes from a class and assigning to a list

Tags: python, class, class-method

I have created a class(City) with several parameters-- name, latitude, longitude, country_name, city_population, population_ratio. population_ratio is created by dividing the City's population by the population of its country (extracted from another class(Country)). The City class has three registries:

```
    _registry_instances = list()
    _registry = dict() ##key = name, value = instance
    _registry_names = list() #list of city names
```

I need to make a class method that returns a tuple of the name of the city with the highest population_ratio and the city name. This is what I have:

```
def cityWithHighestPopulationRatio(City):

    ## create empty list
    cityList = list()

    ## create nested lists of population ratios and names
    ## I've tried a variety of ways to code this including for loops and if statements
    cityList.append([City._registry[population_ratio], City._registry[name]])

    ## assign city with largest ratio to a tuple
    return (max(cityList))
```

No matter how I go about it, I keep getting the error: "NameError: name 'population_ratio' is not defined"

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

```
def cityWithHighestPopulationRatio(City):
   
    cityList = list()
    ## create nested lists of population ratios and names
    for x in City._registry_instances:
        cityList.append([x.population_ratio, x.name])
        
    ## assign city with largest ratio to a tuple
    return (max(cityList))
```

High fives all around! Good work everyone!